# Show auto started desktop app in fullscreen on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, desktop, autostart

I have a working program that has an option to start in fullscreen at start-up.
It's purpose is to be used on an unmanned screen.
It also works as editor for shown content so I rather keep it a desktop app unless there is no other choices.

However in windows 8 the start screen stays on top and my program only show when you go to desktop mode.

What are my options to get the application to show at start-up without manual interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Update to Windows 8.1 in October (which is free for Windows 8 users) and select here that Windows boots to Desktop:

[image: Win8.1: Go to Desktop]

Now it works as you would expect it.